# $scope.$apply undefined angularJS unit testing jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, karma-jasmine

I'm testing a controller containing

```
$document.on('click', $scope.$apply.bind($scope, $scope.deactivate));
```

When I test this controller using Jasmine & Karma

```
'use strict';

describe('controllers: ArrayCtrl', function() {
    var scope;

    beforeEach(module('ironridge'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller('ArrayCtrl', {
                $scope: scope
            });  
        }));

    it('test section ', inject(function($controller) {
        expect(scope.pannels.length).toBe(0);
    }));

});
```

I get the following error :

> PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) controllers: ArrayCtrl should be located in Quote Section FAILED
>       TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$scope.$apply.bind($scope, $scope.deactivate)')
>       undefined
>           at /home/hpro/ironridge/src/app/components/array/array.controller.js:183
>           at invoke (/home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4219)
>           at instantiate (/home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4227)
>           at /home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular/angular.js:8533
>           at /home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1878
>           at /home/hpro/ironridge/src/app/components/array/array.controller.spec.js:11
>           at invoke (/home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4219)
>           at workFn (/home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2437)
>       TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'scope.pannels.length')
>       undefined
>           at /home/hpro/ironridge/src/app/components/array/array.controller.spec.js:17
>           at invoke (/home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4219)
>           at workFn (/home/hpro/ironridge/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2437)

help please

Comment: Can you paste your controller code?

Comment: @MathewBerg this is controller code 
http://pastebin.com/Lz8AnREE

Answer (score 0):

```
$document.on('click', $scope.$apply.bind($scope, $scope.deactivate));
```

I don't think the above code works. I guess you are trying to apply the scope. You can do

```
    $(document).on('click', function(){
        if(!$scope.$$phase){
            $scope.$apply();
        }
        $scope.deactivate();
   });
```

Coming to the test case, bind function in AngularJs is used as

```
angular.bind(self, fn, args)
```

according to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind). In JQuery, bind is used to attach a handler to an event for the elements. In any case $scope.$apply.bind will not work. That is the reason your test case is throwing the error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer 
i have tested 
   
       $(document).on('click', function(){
        if(!$scope.$$phase){
            $scope.$apply();
        }
        $scope.deactivate();
       });

but the action performed just when i click double click